# Angular class encapsulation

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to somehow transform some boolean value inside a class into a string depending of the value so that whenever the class is instantiated it should just transform the boolean from true to 'Yes' and false to 'No'. I'm not sure if encapsulation is the right thing for this but I've read something about it and it seems to be it, I've never used it before and I'm having trouble implementing it.

So I have a class:

```
export class SomeClass{
    public items: Items[] = []
}

class Items {
    link: boolean;
}
```

Is there a way somehow to check inside the class if the value of link is true to transform it into 'Yes' and false to 'No', or maybe add another property _link which is a string and assign it yes or no depending of the link boolean value?

The reason for this is because I want to take care of that at one spot, because this class will be used on multiple components and I dont want to add multiple if/else statements on 10 different components to transform true and false to yes or no.

Answer (score 0):

u can make func at class Items:

```
get strLink(): string { return this.link ? 'Yes' : 'No'; }
```

or when u map array to each item in constructor make second variable (**better**):

```
linkStr: 'Yes'|'No';
constructor(item: Items) {
    this.linkStr = item.link ? 'Yes' : 'No';
}
```

Comment: Does this mean that when i want to instanctiate this class i would have to pass in the "item"? Because the items array is something that is coming from the backend side.

Comment: when u take something from backend u can do this: return http.get<Items[]>(/**/).pipe(map(data => (data || []).map(item => new Items(item))) ); so when u will get Items[] - items alredy mapped to Array<Items> and u can call method or custom property everywhere

Comment: property is better when getter (for example u can do console.log('get') in first row of getter and if u don't use changeDetection: ChangeDetection.onPush u will see a lot of logs where u call this getter

Answer (score 0):

About adding another property called _link returning a string this is easily done as follows:

```
class Items {
    link: boolean;
    
    get _link(): string {
       return this.link ? 'Yes' : 'No';
    }
}
```

Typically you would want to have link property as boolean and only convert it to 'Yes' or 'No' when you display it to the user. In angular, this can be done with a [pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes).

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'yesno'})
export class YesNoPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: boolean): string {
    return value ? 'Yes' : 'No';
  }
}
```

And you use the pipe in HTML like this

```
<div> {{ item.link | yesno }} </div>
```

The pipe approach can be extended is better than having a property because pipes can take advantage of angular dependency injection to add more features. For example you can change the pipe to display Yes and No in different languages.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, LOCALE_ID, Inject } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'yesno'})
export class YesNoPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private readonly locale: string) {}

  transform(value: boolean): string {

    if (this.locale === 'de-DE') {
      // If current language is German 
      return value ? 'Ja' : 'Nein';
    }
    // English is default
    return value ? 'Yes' : 'No';
  }
}
```

The above approach uses [LOCALE_ID](https://angular.io/api/core/LOCALE_ID) to determine the current language and the pipe would display Yes and No in the appropriate language. This is a better approach that having the property in the class itself because:

- It can take advantage of Angular dependency injection to add features like localization
- It allows separation of concerns so your typescript code doesn't have to know how the boolean is displayed
- Pipes offer more reuse because they would work with any boolean value not only the link property in the Items class.

Comment: This seems like a good approach but what if i would like to filter or search by this link value? Even with the pipe if i would type "yes" or "no" in the search field it wouldn't find anything because it is still using the value true or false?

Comment: Your search component should use the same approach. The form control value should be a boolean true or false. And the display can also use the same pipe. For example if you use a dropdown list (select HTML tag). The option tag can have a [ngValue] of true or false, the text of the option tag can display Yes/No, Ja/Nein, etc.

Answer (score -1):

```
export class SomeClass{
  public item: Item;
  public link;
  SomeClass() {
    link = item.link ? "yes" : "no"
  };
}

class Item {
link: boolean;
}
```

I don't really understand your question, but it might be the answer.